# Unable to access Front page of a customized Wordpress Theme

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I need help.  I'm a designer not a developer.  I've been asked to update the front page of a WordPress site that has a customized theme.  The only problem is that I can't access the page.  The developer who wrote the theme is incognito - no one can find him.  The theme was built using jquery, ajax and php.  I can grab the source code located on the Front page at cchwb.org through Mozilla, but the code is locked and I can't make changes.  Also, I can't find the page in the Hostgagtor cPanel that reflects the code that I was able to capture.  The page identified as Static in the Customize area indicates Home, but when I open it in the Dashboard it's blank.  When I view it in the browser it looks like the default page rather than the Front page. Any advice?

Comment: If you go to `Appearance` >> `Editor` in the WordPress admin and look at the `Main Index Template (index.php)`, does this have the code you are looking to edit?

Comment: When I open the site through a browser using http://cchwb.org/index.php I see the landing page I need to modify; however, the index.php file that I view by going into the WP Dashboard through Appearance>>Editor>>index.php is Greek to me.  When I copy & paste it into Dreamer, it shows the typical PHP header & some text.  The majority of the pg is a series of PHP icons (square gold boxes labeled PHP).  So, I can't see the actual front pg content other than thru capturing the .htm code.  And, I can't locate the .htm file in the Hostgator cPanel folders in order to make the changes. Any ideas?

Comment: The front page is dynamically generated, either from one of the theme files or from a post/page (Home as you indicated in customize, but since this was blank it must be coming from a theme file).  The page is not going to be one of the files you see in Hostgator's control panel.  Most likely it is the theme index.php file which should be edited in a text editor, not Dreamweaver as that may not give you the whole picture since its PHP.

Comment: I pasted the index.php into Word (hopefully, that's what you meant by a text editor), but again, there's nothing in the index.php that resembles the current content - e.g., text, images or videos.  I continued to look through the files in the cPanel & found the error log.  This error began March 2014 & keeps recurring.  Do you think this is what is causing my problem?  [29-Jun-2015 01:16:18 UTC] PHP Catchable fatal error:  Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string in /home4/clinic77/public_html/wp-content/themes/CCHWB/functions.php on line 80